# Reasons for killer fishes?

Tags: aquarium, fish

I've got a recurring problem with killer fish. In the last 3 years I repeatedly had recurring sudden spikes in fish deaths.
Via pure coincidence I found out that it was no strange sickness or water values, but instead fish killing one another (I saw one of the cases).
The "murderers" were mostly sword bearers and black mollies. Strangely the females if I'm not mistaken (sadly I watched it only through the corner of my eyes so not 100% sure).

The things they killed were members of other species like a black molly killing a sword bearer and vice versa. Also other fish types were victims.

What is strange to me is....space shouldn't be an issue as it is a 31,7 gallon (120l) tank with a few caves and quite a few plants.

For the "killing method" it was so that the murderer bit into the forehead of the other fish, which then panicked, and swam upward and away with all speed....the speed being so high that it jumped out of the water and hit the lid of the aquarium with full force....the result for a human would have been a neck breaking equivalent from what I saw. The fish then sank down and shuddered for a few moments before lying still and being dead.

So far it has been about 3 fish that went on killing sprees... each killing 2-6 others over the course of weeks. That is before 1-2 months after the deaths started....they died themselves and the death rate sank to 0 again.

So far I found nothing indicating any reason for this behaviour (only found a bit about males and space, but at least 1 was very probably a female).

My question is: Are there any other possibilities on what I'm doing wrong there....so that my fish become so overly aggressive?

(Aside from the killing sprees I saw no strange behaviour for any of the species or involved specimen).

Comment: I had a similar setup (fish) in my 10-15 liters bowl some years ago, and I had absolutely no problem. Most of the fishes were mollies (whatever was "cheap", usually the black and red kinds, "all" shapes). Additionally I had a few albino corridoras, one ancistrus and one beta splendens. Is the aquarium aerated? Are the fish in the mating period? Do they have "babies"? Is there vegetation in the aquarium?

Comment: No nobö babies at that time and no mating period half the time. Vegetation: yes not a full one but 6 „islands“ of vegatation are inside @virolino

Comment: Then you might have the situation I was told about years ago: sometimes the fish are crazy. I saw the betta attacking other fishes occasionally, and I saw (in pet shop aquariums) other fishes attacking betta. Are they fed properly (I assume yes)? Insufficient food might lead to fights, I guess. It is common in other species, including humans. Do you feed them only dry food? Maybe they lack some nutrients. Try providing them with (frozen) worms and other "natural" food and see what happens.

Comment: The 120l tank says nothing about space if you not say how many fish are in it.

Comment: @Allerleirauh about 20-30  (with 10 being ember tetra)

Comment: @virolino as I know betta are very special in "fight behavior" because they are very territorial. Maybe they are not the best example?

Comment: One rule of thumb is "1cm fish needs 1l of water". If I assume you have 10 ember tetra (10x2cm), 10 black molly (10x10cm) and 10 sword bearer / swordtail (10x13cm) it summs up to over 200l of water. Maybe the jumping behavior causes in no other free space to swim away from the Attacke? I could not imagine a fish to plan the death of another a way like that...

Comment: @Allerleirauh: you have a good point, OP should make an analysis of his setup. However, as I said, I had a VERY small bowl (10-15 liters, never really measured), and easily in excess of 100cm of fish, and no problem with killing or jumping - except for some exceptions of corridoras darting to the surface and back to the bottom, but never jumping out of the water.

Comment: @Allerleirauh: even with the betta, I did not have problems. It lived in the crowded space with everyone, with no aggression. But yes, there is higher risk of fights when a (male) betta is around.

Comment: @Allerleirauh hmmm from what you say about their size it seems like what is called  swordtail here is a smaller sub type...way smaller.   the embers I would say 1-1.5cm  the sword tails and black mollies max.3-5cm each (all adults already). as for the jumping out of the water: I only ever watched that behaviour on two occasions...once: Fish was absolutely in panic mode (put into the tank, and was scared to death...managed to jump onto the in tank filter and into a small hole there...landing inside the filter).  And the other time with the head bite from the "killer".

Comment: @virolino that it works one time is no evidence for a general working thing ;)

Comment: @Allerleirauh: true, very true. I did not event intend to claim that generalization is possible or recommended. Just that it can happen.

Comment: @Thomas I have looked at wikipedia for the fish length. I could not see your fish  :D but all fish growing their whole live, so "adult" mean nothing in body length

Comment: @Allerleirauh "adult" I meant: 3 year old and didnt see any spurts of growth for quite some time with them :)